# Assign multiple values to single row Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame.

|  | USER_ID | USER_NAME | USER_REPUTATION | NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS | NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS | BADGE_NAME | BADGE_CAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Ahmad Anis | 123 | 2 | 3 | Topper | HTML |
| 1 | 1 | Ahmad Anis | 123 | 2 | 3 | programmer | Random |

I want to convert it to following

|  | USER_ID | USER_NAME | USER_REPUTATION | NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS | NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS | BADGE_NAME | BADGE_CAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Ahmad Anis | 123 | 2 | 3 | Topper | HTML |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  | programmer | Random |

I can not display it correctly, but I do not want it to repeat similar things again, instead make them a big box, and uncommon things are displayed. I tried using multi-indexing but it was not working.

I want something similar to this

[image]

But here it is only doing it with single column, I want it to do it with my USER_ID, USER_NAME, USER_REPUTATION, NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS columbs

Comment: Do you want `df.drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: No, I want something related to multiindex. I have edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `set_index`:

```
cols = ["USER_ID", "USER_NAME", "USER_REPUTATION", "NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS", "NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS"]

ndf = df.set_index(cols)
```

with some sample data:

```
>>> df
      A  B    C         D         E
0   one  A  foo  0.945847 -0.561259
1   one  A  foo  0.579520  0.130518
2   one  A  foo -0.683629 -1.084639
3   one  A  bar -0.168223 -0.311991
4   one  B  bar  0.007965  1.108121
5   one  B  bar -1.877323 -0.258055
6   one  B  bar  0.992160  0.192339
7   one  B  foo -0.421557 -0.805156
8   two  C  bar -0.346622  1.335197
9   two  C  foo -0.979483 -1.382465
10  two  C  bar -0.815332 -1.491385
11  two  C  foo -2.112730 -0.331574

>>> cols = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> ndf = df.set_index(cols)
>>> ndf

                  D         E
A   B C
one A foo  0.945847 -0.561259
      foo  0.579520  0.130518
      foo -0.683629 -1.084639
      bar -0.168223 -0.311991
    B bar  0.007965  1.108121
      bar -1.877323 -0.258055
      bar  0.992160  0.192339
      foo -0.421557 -0.805156
two C bar -0.346622  1.335197
      foo -0.979483 -1.382465
      bar -0.815332 -1.491385
      foo -2.112730 -0.331574
```

`ndf` is now a multi index frame.

---

To make the `D` and `E` at the same level as the `A`, `B` and `C`, we can set the index to all of them for the display purposes:

```
the_df = df.set_index(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
```

to get (in an IPython notebook, for example)

[image]

Note that if you were to look at this in console:

```
>>> the_df

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(one, A, foo, 0.945847, -0.561259), (one, A, foo, 0.57952, 0.130518), ...]
```

because we set everything to the index and nothing remained in the values! But if you'd like to see it in the console as well, one trick is to use a "ghost" column, i.e., with name and values being the empty string `""`:

```
>>> the_df[""] = ""
>>> the_df

A   B C   D         E
one A foo  0.945847 -0.561259
           0.579520  0.130518
          -0.683629 -1.084639
      bar -0.168223 -0.311991
    B bar  0.007965  1.108121
          -1.877323 -0.258055
           0.992160  0.192339
      foo -0.421557 -0.805156
two C bar -0.346622  1.335197
      foo -0.979483 -1.382465
      bar -0.815332 -1.491385
      foo -2.112730 -0.331574
```

---

removing the extra first row in HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# form the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_df.to_html())

# find the first row and remove it
soup.find("tr").extract()

# get HTML back
html = str(soup)
```

Comment: This is more suitable and correct. 1 thing, if you see the D and E are 1 row above then A B C. Can we make them at same level, and achieve the results?

Comment: @AhmadAnis Sure, it can be done via setting all the column names as the index. Edited the answer.

Comment: It is adding an extra row at the top of Index, when I render it in HTML, I can see it.

Comment: @AhmadAnis I see, if you have BeautifulSoup, I added a way to remove that in HTML.

Comment: Works perfectly fine now